# Removing string quotes around a list of dictionary

Tags: python

I'm hoping someone could help me with this problem. I have a string that looks this way

```
    a = '[{"name": "bob", "age":"11", "participantid":"Me", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, how you doing."}, {{"name": "Roland", "age":"16", "participantid":"boy", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, I'm doing good and you?."}]'
```

And my goal is to return the list instead of string, so I'm expecting something like this:

```
    a = [{"name": "bob", "age":"11", "participantid":"Me", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, how you doing."}, {{"name": "Roland", "age":"16", "participantid":"boy", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, I'm doing good and you?."}]
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, I've used replace and strip, but none works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
print(json.loads(a))
```

Or this:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(a))
```

Comment: Please accept the answer then by making the tick on left green.